# I want to show a given sequence is in L^1 so that I can apply DCT.

Tags: real-analysis

(a) State the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

The Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem states: let $\{g_n\} \in L^1$ for all $n$. If there exists a positive $f \in L^1$ such that $|\{g_n\}|\leq f$ and $g_n \to g$ then $g\in L^1$ and $\int g=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_n$.

(b) Let $f:\Bbb R\to[-\infty,\infty]$ be a Lebesgue integrable function. For $n \in \Bbb N$, let $h_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $h_n(x)=\frac{3e^{nx}}{2+e^{nx}}$. Show that the sequence $(\int(h_nf))$ is convergent.  Determine its limit.

Let $g_n=h_n(x)f$ and $g=3f$.

I am unsure how to show $\{g_n\} \in L^1$.
For now I assume $\{g_n\} \in L^1$
For all n, $\lim_{x\to\infty} h_n(x) = 3$ Furthermore $h_n(x)$ is a strictly positive increasing function so $|h_n(x)|<3$ for all $n$ thus $|\{g_n\}|\leq 3f$. Note that $3f\in L^1$.  Therefore by the DCT $\int \lim_{n\to \infty} h_n(x)f = \int 3f = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int h_n(x)f$.

I believe everything else is just fine. Please alert me if not.

Comment: You know $|g_n|\leq 3|f|$ so the integral of $g_n$ is finite.

Comment: This is generally right, but I would suggest you carefully prove that $h_n$ is increasing, and explain how this leads to the conclusion that $|h_n(x)|<3$.

Comment: Indeed, by Michael's comment, the assumption "$\{g_n\} \in L^1$" in your statement is redundant.